# Modifying DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH for mysql, python, and django

Tags: python

I've seen two dozen posts concerning this issue, but I'm so NOOB I'm not sure how to modify everything correctly.

I'm attempting to finish the installation, but when I go to Python and "import MySQLdb" I end up getting:

```
ImportError: dlopen(/Users/pccampbell/.python-eggs/MySQL_python-1.2.3-py2.7-macosx-10.5-fat3.egg-tmp/_mysql.so, 2):


Library not loaded: libmysqlclient.16.dylib
```

Referenced from: /Users/pccampbell/.python-eggs/MySQL_python-1.2.3-py2.7-macosx-10.5-fat3.egg-tmp/_mysql.so

I then run this command which everyone says works (and it does, but only temporarily!):

```
export DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/mysql/lib/
```

SO, I'm trying to execute the following to permanently change the path (as found on another help site):

```
sudo install_name_tool -change libmysqlclient.16.dylib /usr/local/mysql/lib/libmysqlclient.16.dylib lib/python2.7/site-packages/_mysql.so
```

BUT, I end up getting this error:

```
install_name_tool: can't open file: lib/python2.7/site-packages/_mysql.so (No such file or directory)
```

I found the _mysql.so file at, but even when I use this path it doesn't work:

```
/Users/pccampbell/MySQL-python-1.2.3/build/lib.macosx-10.5-fat3-2.7
```

THE BOTTOM LINE: is there a way to permanently modify the DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH, so I don't have to run the export command every time. If so, then could you please, please, please provide the specific syntax, because I've been guessing and checking for a long time. :(

ANy help GREATLY appreciated.

Patrick

Answer (score 14):

According to Matt's idea, in mac os x Lion, you should add the following sentence like this to your /etc/profile:

```
export DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/mysql/lib:$DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH
```

Answer (score 8):

add the export command to /etc/profile as follows:

```
export DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/mysql/lib
```

Note:There is no "/" after lib above. If you add / after lib, and try installing MySQL-python, the errors will keep occuring when running ">>import MySQLdb"

I hope this solves the problem for you! :-)