# python accessing mysql db not able to load the library

Tags: python, mysql, database, osx-lion

I am using python 2.7 and MySQLdb, while doing import MySQLdb its throwing below error -

```
import MySQLdb
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/MySQLdb/__init__.py", line 19, in <module>
    import _mysql
ImportError: dlopen(/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/_mysql.so, 2): Library not loaded: libmysqlclient.18.dylib
  Referenced from: /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/_mysql.so
  Reason: image not found
```

Comment: Add the path in etc/profile > export DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/mysql/lib:$DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5081574/modifying-dyld-library-path-for-mysql-python-and-django

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to have the mysql client installed on your system.

If you have, then you have the file `libmysqlclient.18.dylib` located somewhere on your system. Make sure the path where it is located is included in your `DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH` environment variable.

Comment: i do have client installed and path is included for environment variable
more ~/.bash_profile
DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=$DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH:/usr/local/mysql/lib/
PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/mysql/bin:/Users/Jaimin/Development/Django-1.3.1/django/bin/

Comment: Is the file `libmysqlclient.18.dylib` in the folder `/usr/local/mysql/lib/`? If not, is a different version located there?

Comment: file is there, here is the list of file in there >libmysqlclient.18.dylib  libmysqlclient_r.18.dylib libmysqld-debug.a  plugin
libmysqlclient.a  libmysqlclient_r.a  libmysqld.a
libmysqlclient.dylib  libmysqlclient_r.dylib  libmysqlservices.a

Comment: Unless you are starting python from a bash shell (not the terminal app) you need to set the environment variables in your `environment.plist`. Editing `.bash_profile` affects only bash shells (and only if you restarted your mac)

Comment: :) I am starting from terminal app and have restarted mac right after install and setting up bash_profile...tried to read the variable on terminal it doesn't recognize though it recognize PATH from it..so really not sure whats going on.

Comment: Like I wrote before the terminal app is not the same as the bash shell. If you edit your `.bash_profile` then those changes affect only bash shells but not the terminal app. To set environment variables for the terminal (and other window apps) edit your `environment.plist`.

Comment: Thanks Chris...i found the answer in one of the other post. I added in question's comments.